# I'm able to edit other user's posts [JWT auth]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, jwt

Reactjs code for editing a post :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/authContext';
import config from '../config.json';

const Edit = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [post, setPost] = useState({
    title: '',
    desc: '',
    cat: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setPost((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios.put(`${config.SERVER_URL}/api/posts/${id}`, post);
      navigate('/');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(`${config.SERVER_URL}/api/posts/${id}`);
      console.log(data.data[0]);
      setPost(data.data[0]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  if (currentUser) {
    return (
      <>
        {currentUser.username === post.username ? (
          <>
            <div className='auth text-center'>
              <div className='display-6 m-4'>Update Post</div>
              <form>
                <div>
                  <input
                    type='text'
                    className='m-4 p-2 rounded-4'
                    placeholder='Title'
                    value={post.title}
                    name='title'
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <textarea
                    type='text'
                    className='m-4 p-2 rounded-4'
                    placeholder='Description'
                    value={post.desc}
                    name='desc'
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input
                    type='text'
                    className='m-4 p-2 rounded-4'
                    placeholder='Category'
                    value={post.cat}
                    name='cat'
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className='text-center m-4'>
                  <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={handleSubmit}>
                    Update Post
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div className='auth display-6'>You cannot edit this post!</div>
          </>
        )}
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <div className='auth display-6'>Not Logged in!</div>
      </>
    );
  }
};

export default Edit;
```

Auth Context :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import config from '../config.json';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContexProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || null
  );

  const login = async (inputs) => {
    const res = await axios.post(`${config.SERVER_URL}/api/auth/login`, inputs);
    setCurrentUser(res.data);
  };

  const logout = async (inputs) => {
    await axios.post(`${config.SERVER_URL}/api/auth/logout`);
    setCurrentUser(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(currentUser));
  }, [currentUser]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Nodejs backend code :

```
export const updatePost = (req, res) => {
  const token = req.cookies.access_token;
  if (!token) return res.status(401).json('Not authenticated!');

  jwt.verify(token, 'jwtkey', (err, userInfo) => {
    if (err) return res.status(403).json('Token is not valid!');

    const values = [req.body.title, req.body.desc, req.body.cat];
    const id = req.params.id;
    const q = 'Update posts set `title`=?,`desc`=?,`cat`=? where id = ? ;';

    db.query(q, [...values, id], (err, data) => {
      if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);

      return res.status(200).send(data);
    });
  });
};
```

Here the details of the logged in user is stored in the localstorage.
I' able to edit the localstorage and change the username to match the post username and edit the post which is not supposed to happen.

Is there another way to design this to prevent it from happening.

I just started with web development, I'd appreciate someone's help :)

Comment: You need to check that the user's ID matches the post's user's ID in your code somewhere.

Comment: As I'm also creating the user view, the user's ID is exposed in the URL!

Comment: IDs typically are not considered sensitive. For example, yours here is 19984245. https://stackoverflow.com/users/19984245/rohith-badrinath

Comment: You can add backend check as well. From jwt verify you get userInfo. In update query you could include it which will fail the update.